# How to use z3 with Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, z3

I want to use Z3 with Visual Studio 2015. I downloaded the binaries for the current version (4.4.1) for Windows. Then I set up a new project, add the include-folder to the include directories and the bin folder to the librariy directories. My current main file (and only file) is:

```
#include <z3++.h>

void main() {
  z3::context ctx;
  z3::expr expr = ctx.bool_val(4);
}
```

However, when I try to run this with the local windows debugger, a number of Linker errors are shown, e.g., unresolved external symbol _Z3_mk_config referenced in ... . So, apparently, I'm missing something, but I don't know what.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: did you add the lib to the additional library dependencies? (which is different from adding the folder because that only tells VS where to look for .lib)

Comment: Yes, you need to tell the linker to link with libz3.lib (later the .dll has to be in the path when you run the program, that's basically what the content of libz3.lib describes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, thanks to the comments I could finally solve the problem:

I needed to add the libz3.dll to Additional Dependencies in Linker->Inputs
and the lib folder to Additional Library Dependencies in Linker->General.

Thank you for your help!